# Alternate wording for 'verification and validation'

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

In technical contexts the idea of 'verification and validation' is often used. However novices to the terminology (or so I claim) on more occasions display a hard time grabbing and remembering which concept is which, or even what are they.

An example expression of this confusion can be seen in 
[Difference between "validation" and "verification"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/53866/23199)

It would be unfortunate if people talking about the things meant by either verification or validation would have unclear ideas of what they are talking about. This is a field where communication should be clear. Eg. you don't want to lose time verifying your communication *about* verification...

I think the problem with the two term may include that they both start with `v`, end with `ion`, are generally somehow unfamiliar in precise meaning, denote somehow abstract things, not to speak of the fact that they can include or apply to each other (eg. 'verification is validation by empirical means'). So all in all, introducing them together is risky and inherently prone to errors.

I'm looking for alternate wording for either or both of these words, assuming they each have a single intended meaning. If suitable terms could be found that better express their difference, the learning curve to their usage hopefully could be shortened.

Comment: In simpler, loosely-applied terms, *to check* and *to confirm*? That is, see if it is what it ought to be (verify) and then test it to prove that it really is what it claims to be (validate).

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to learn that validation is checking whether something conforms to rules while verification is checking whether a claim is true.

Answer (score 1):

Validation will always come prior to Verification like they do alphabetically.

You can use the following in case you still want to switch :

Validation : sanctioning
Verification : Corroboration, confirmation

Answer (score 0):

In simpler terms it *passed inspection* and is in *working-order*.  Borrowing from building code terminology.

Comment: But do these correspond to what *verification* and *validation* mean for computer software?

Comment: @PeterShor - to a non-techie yes.  I understand what V&V is because I go through it.  My apps have to pass a series of inspections and then I have to prove out to a user test group that they work.  You could probably just go with inspection(s).

Comment: [Please use *italics* not **bold** for the use–mention distinction on ELU.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/364).

Answer (score 0):

How about "tested and approved?"

> *Some nonstandard software has been [**tested and approved**](http://www.oregon.gov/DAS/ETS/TSC/Pages/tsc_ordering.aspx) by TSC*.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *empirical confirmation* and *support*.

> My colleague's elegant interpretation of past experiments in the context of our hypothesis provided *support* for our ideas, but we finally gained *empirical* *confirmation* for our hypothesis when we received the results of the new experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to www.dictionary.com, **validation** is:

"1. to make valid; substantiate; confirm:
Time validated our suspicions. 
2. to give legal force to; legalize."

While **verification** is defined as:

"1. the act of verifying.
2. the state of being verified."

So if we break it down to the basic terms *valid* and *verified*, *valid* is defined as:

"1. sound; just; well-founded 
2. producing the desired result; effective"

*Verified* is defined as, "confirmed as to accuracy or truth by acceptable evidence, action, etc."

So, that says to me, valid is reason or emotionally based while verified is evidentially based. 
Now all you have to do is look up synonyms for those.

Instead of **validation**, you could use **justification**. Instead of **verification**, you could use **confirmation** or **authentication**.